# ¿Por qué no se me muestran los estilos de Tailwind-CSS en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, tailwind, laravel-jetstream

*Cree el proyecto con la siguiente instrucción*

laravel new blog --jet

*luego corro*

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

*cree el componente Alert*

```
php artisan make:component Alert
```

*el código de alert.blade.php es:*

```
<div class="flex p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-blue-700 bg-blue-100 rounded-lg" role="alert">
    <svg class="inline w-5 h-5 mr-3" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 10a8 8 0 11-16 0 8 8 0 0116 0zm-7-4a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zM9 9a1 1 0 000 2v3a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 100-2v-3a1 1 0 00-1-1H9z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    <div>
        <span class="font-medium">Info alert!</span> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
    </div>
</div>
```

*y llamo al componente con el código*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        @livewireStyles

        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="container max-w-lg mx-auto">

            <x-alert/>

        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

        @livewireScripts

    </body>
</html>
```

*debería salir esto*

[[image: salida supuesta tomada de https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/tailwind-css-alerts][1]]

*Pero obtengo esto*

[image: resultado no deseado]

¿Alguien puede decirme por qué Tailwind no está funcionando?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: fíjate en la consola de desarrollo del navegador si te están cargando los CSS

Comment: Si lo hace aparece: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blog.test/css/app.css">

Comment: En app.css está cargado tailwind. no voy a poner todo pero empienza con /*! tailwindcss v2.2.19 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com *//*! modern-normalize v1.1.0 | MIT License | https://github.com/sindresorhus/modern-normalize */

/*
Document
========
*/

Comment: Al cambiar blue por indigo se corrige, sin embargo noto que necesito colores que no aparecen en la paleta básica. ¿Alguien sabe como agregarlas desde tailwind css ink

Comment: YA viste la respuesta que te dieron te lo soluciona???

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve este problema, y si, los recursos css y js del app cargaban correctamente. Les explico a detalle las características de mi proyecto:

- Utilizaba laravel 9
- Había instalado el paquete JetStream a través de composer
- Al instalar este paquete automáticamente se añade livewire y Tailwind-CSS
- El proyecto trabajaba con **vite** y no con **webpack**

Todo me funcionaba bien, pero al querer añadir nuevos estilos no lo cargaba, encontré foros donde recomendaban ejecutar en la terminal

```
npm run dev 
npm run watch
```

Al momento de ejecutar run watch me daba error, y era porque no lo tenía añadido en mi archivo **package.json**

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Así que lo único que hice fue añadir la siguiente línea de código: **"watch": "vite build --watch"**, lo muestro en mi archivo para que quedé más claro:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "watch": "vite build --watch"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
    "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
}
```

Ahora ya me funcionan ambos comandos y se cargan los estilos correctamente, encontré la respuesta [aquí.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72848322/is-the-npm-run-watch-property-already-in-laravel-vite)

Answer (score 0):

reeplace el codigo de

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

por

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

en lavare los archivos tipo js y css utiliza la función **asset()**

si la ruta de los archivos son

***public/js/app.js***

***public/css/app.css***

si desea verifica si el archivo se esta cargado corretamente puede presiona **F11** y en **red/network** puede verifica los archivos se esta cargado el código 404 significa que el archivo no fue encontrado y 200 carga exitosa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo error y no lo pude solucionar haciendo el cambio en la etiqueta link con la función asset y tampoco trayendo la versión anterior de tailwind.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única solución que pude encontrar fue personalizando los colores, espero estos recursos te ayuden:

https://youtu.be/KMFkMfy90R0

https://tailwind.ink/code

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tambien batalle un rato con esto, en mi caso, la solución fue pasar la hoja de estilos de la siguiente forma...

> ```
>     <!-- Styles -->
>              @vite('resources/css/app.css')
>     <!-- /Styles -->
> ```

En lugar de :

> ```
>     <!-- Styles -->
>              <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
>     <!-- /Styles -->
> ```

Cierto, hay que tener bien las rutas en "tailwindcss.config.js":

> "export defailt{content:[         //Se añaden extras...
> "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
> "./resources/**/*.js",
> "./resources/**/**.vue",  ] ...}"